# Is ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework still supported by Microsoft?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I'd like to know if ASP.NET Core - specifically version 2.1 - is still supported **if it is running on the .NET Framework runtime**. With "supported" I only mean "is still getting security fixes" in the context of this question.

According to the [.NET Core and .NET 5 Support Policy](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core):

> **ASP.NET Core 2.1 on .NET Framework**
>
> Support for ASP.NET Core 2.1 on .NET Framework matches the [ASP.NET Support](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/aspnet) policy for other package-based ASP.NET frameworks. The complete list of packages covered by this policy can be seen in [ASP.NET Core 2.1 Supported Packages](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/aspnetcore-2.1).

The first link ([ASP.NET Support](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/aspnet)) says this:

> [...] the following ASP.NET Core 2.1 (latest patched version only) [packages](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/aspnetcore-2.1) will be supported on the .NET Framework and follow the [support cycle](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=.net%20framework) for those .NET Framework versions.

Although there is no "following" list, I assume they mean the [packages](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/aspnetcore-2.1) link. That page lists ASP.NET Core packages, e.g. the "main" package "Microsoft.AspNetCore".

So all of this seems to indicate that ASP.NET Core 2.1 on .NET Framework is still supported.

**Question 1:** Is this correct?

But the last released [AspNetCore package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore/) is 2.1.7 from January 2019, whereas the [current 2.1.x version of .NET Core](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1) is 2.1.24 from January 2021.

**Question 2:** Why are there no updates for the ASP.NET Core NuGet package for 2 years even though it should still be supported?

If it's still supported, doesn't this also mean that ASP.NET Core 2.1 on .NET Framework is supported as long as the .NET Framework itself is supported - which bascially means as long as the Windows version it's running on is supported? So even after .NET Core 2.1 support ends on August 21, 2021, ASP.NET Core 2.1 on .NET Framework should still get security updates, right?

**Question 3:** Is this correct, so will we basically get security updates "forever"?

Comment: The real question should be `Is .NET Old (Framework) still supported?`. Only for security fixes. ASP.NET Core 3 and later come out only for .NET Core. .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5.

Comment: The docs you link to clearly explain those packages are maintained `To help facilitate migrating applications to ASP.NET Core on .NET Core`. The change is nothing new, it was announced during .NET Core 3's development and upon release, in articles, blog posts etc

Comment: The edit repeats the same question with different wording expecting a different answer in order to ...  do what? The ASP.NET Core team won't change its release plans. Even if they admit the wording in the page is wrong (it's not), all they have to do is edit the. page. It's not like you have a paid contract with them. The packages exist only to allow migration. The engineering answer is `Upgrade`.

Comment: The business answer may be `Upgrade`, `Buy a support contract` or `leave it alone`. Getting the security updates is `leave it alone`, as it's up to the customer's IT to install the Windows Updates when they come out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got an answer from a Microsoft employee [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/discussions/29445).

TLDR: Yes, ASP.NET Core 2.1 on .NET Framework ist still supported and will be supported as long as the .NET Framework. The NuGet package didn't get any updates because they don't publish new packages for transitive reference updates.

**Edit:** Sadly Microsoft disabled the discussions on the linked repository, so the post is no longer available. (Edit 2: Now enabled again!) But a [recent blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-2-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-august-21-2021/) that highlighted the end of life of .NET Core 2.1 it was also mentioned that this doesn't affect ASP.NET Core 2.1 on .NET Framework:

> Note: support for ASP.NET Core 2.1 on .NET Framework matches the
> support policy of the .NET Framework. See the [ASP.NET Support Policy](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/aspnet)
> for more details

The linked ASP.NET Support Policy contains this:

> To help facilitate migrating applications to ASP.NET Core on .NET
> Core, the following ASP.NET Core 2.1 (latest patched version only)
> [packages](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/aspnetcore-2.1) will be supported on the .NET Framework and follow the
> [support cycle](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=.net%20framework) for those .NET Framework versions. ASP.NET Core 2.1 is
> defined as "Tools" in the Microsoft Support Lifecycle Policy. A "Tool"
> requires a minimum of 12 months notification prior to the end of
> support. For more information, please see [this KB Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/troubleshoot/aspnet/support-lifecycle-web-stack?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website).

The "packages" link links to the page "[ASP.NET Core 2.1 and ASP.NET 5.2.7 Supported Packages](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/aspnetcore-2.1)". That page states

> The package lists below represents the supported ASP packages when
> using ASP.NET Core 2.1 on .NET Framework.

Comment: I asked the same [question](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/25171#issuecomment-1059496733) and get the same [answer](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/25171#issuecomment-1059499579).

Comment: Do you know if the support policy for aspnetcore 2.1 is the same as aspnetcore 2.2 running on .net framework? @vernou  I'm having trouble finding any information regarding 2.2

Comment: @WillGunn, Disclaimer, I don't work at Microsoft, it's just that I understand. Only 2.1 has a exception. ASP.NET 2.2 follow .NET Core 2.2 support... that is ended at 23/12/2019.

Comment: @WillGunn,  I found this [comment](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-2-2-will-reach-end-of-life-on-december-23-2019/#comment-4744) from the .NET Blog that confirm my assumption.

Answer (score 2):

"Supported" is not the same as "under active development"; it means that you might be able to get some help if there's a problem *within what it is already intended to do* - it doesn't mean that you get new features or APIs.

In reality, though; it would be highly inadvisable to start any *new* work on any version of .NET Core prior to 3.1 (at the time of writing), or to start any new projects on .NET Framework (any version), without first understanding *exactly* why you are doing that - both what you are gaining, and what you are sacrificing. All new work should (frankly) target .NET 3.1, or if you want "the new new", .NET 5 *but bearing in mind* that .NET 5 is not an LTS release, so this should just be a temporary target, with a view of moving to .NET 6 (which is LTS) when that is available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm not concerned about new projects, only about existing code. I added some additional information to the question.

Comment: I've restructured my post and added an additional question. Could you please check if you can help with my specific questions?

Answer (score -3):

The [support page link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/aspnet) in the question clearly explains [those packages](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/aspnetcore-2.1) are maintained

> To help facilitate migrating applications to ASP.NET Core on .NET Core.

The change is nothing new, it was announced during .NET Core 3's development and upon release, in articles, blog posts etc.

ASP.NET Core 2.1 on .NET Core 2.1 gets frequent updates because it follows .NET Core 2.1's support policy. .NET Core 2.1 and .NET Core 3.1 are long-term support versions, which means they're supported for 3 years after release. This is explained in the [.NET Core Support Policy](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core). BTW 2.1's support end on August 2021, so you'd better migrate to 3.1.

The real question should be `Is .NET Old (Framework) still supported?`. Only for security fixes. ASP.NET Core 3 and later come out only for .NET Core. .NET 5 is .NET Core 5.

It's time to upgrade

**Where to get the Security Updates**

Through Windows Update. Fixes and patches for .NET Framework are released through the [.NET Framework Security and Quality Rollup](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-january-security-and-quality-rollup-update/) updates.

Comment: Thanks for your anwer. But I'm not concerned about ASP.NET Core 2.1 on the .NET Core 2.1 runtime. I'm only concerned about ASP.NET Core 2.1 on the .NET Framework runtime. And as far as I understand those articles, that support shouldn't end in 2021, but run as long as the .NET Framework is supported. Or am I wrong? Note that I also added a bit more information to the question.

Comment: I've restructured my post and added an additional question. Could you please check if you can help with my specific questions?

Comment: @cremor the only specific question is where to get security updates. The same way you get them for .NET Framework, through the [.NET Framework Security and Quality Rollup Updates](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-january-security-and-quality-rollup-update/)  available through Windows Update

Comment: ASP.NET Core is not part of the .NET Framework. It's shipped as a NuGet package. So it can't be a part of the .NET Framework updates itself.