# How to update ASP.NET Core 2.1 (running on .NET Framework) to newer builds?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-4.8

I have an old app running on ASP.NET Core 2.1 *and running on .NET Framework* (yes, [that is a thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65851144/34092)).

OK fine. But I need to update that old project to include some [new updates](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3848) - specifically patched `UseCookiePolicy` support - as described at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/comment-page-3/ - and some other security patches).

Extract from the csproj file:

```
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreModuleName>AspNetCoreModuleV2</AspNetCoreModuleName>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

So we can see that the ASP.NET Core dependencies are referenced via NuGet.

OK, fine - so I need to go and update those packages. But here comes the issue - the packages *don't exist any more*. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore/2.1.7 is the latest version, but alas that was released prior to the fixes that I need. https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/217 is the announcement where they said they would stop generating the NuGet packages.

So now I am a bit stuck. I can download the latest SDK etc from https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/2.1/2.1.30/2.1.30.md#downloads - but how do I change my project from its NuGet references to the files at C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared instead?

*You may be tempted to suggest using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.34#supportedframeworks-body-tab - but that doesn't work either since it explicitly excludes .NET Framework support.*

.NET Core 2.1 on .NET Framework is a supported thing. How do other people solve this upgrade problem?

Comment: `Microsoft made it clear to everyone that ASP.NET Core releases were going to have a very short supported lifetime` As per https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/aspnet#dotnet-core "To help facilitate migrating applications to ASP.NET Core on .NET Core, the specified ASP.NET Core 2.1 packages (latest patched version only) will be supported on the .NET Framework and follow the support cycle for those .NET Framework versions." Microsoft's official policy is that ASP.NET Core 2.1 on Framework is supported the same as System.Web.

Comment: Hi, I just want to say, if it's possible, then we'd better to have a plan to upgrade the old project to a newer long time support .net version so that we could use the new feature and related nuget packages..... I know it's not related to your issue, it's just my humble opinion.

Comment: Obviously yes @TinyWang. That is the longer term plan - but doesn't help for the short term.

Comment: Yes, I also met similar migration issue before which is caused by nuget packages, and finally I was suggested to create a new project with .net 6 or even with .net 8 because it's too old to migrate step by step. That's really sad...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite/mvc21?view=aspnetcore-2.1#targeting-net-framework / https://stackoverflow.com/a/65834637/34092 is the solution. I will close this as duplicate once the bounty closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC SameSite cookie sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite/mvc21?view=aspnetcore-2.1#targeting-net-framework) (found via https://stackoverflow.com/a/65834637/34092):

> To get the ASP.NET Core changes for .NET Framework ensure that you
> have a direct reference to the patched packages and versions (2.1.14
> or later 2.1 versions).

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers" Version="2.1.14" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy" Version="2.1.14" />
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/discussions/29445#discussioncomment-303018):

> As for packages, in the 2.1 world, we only publish packages that are directly affected by a servicing change, we don't push all packages, or all packages that transitively reference the affected package.
> This isn't ideal because it means you have to watch for bulletins in packages you transitively depend on and lift them, but there other reasons that make it difficult for us to re-publish all transitive packages.

Meaning: There won't be an update for the Microsoft.AspNetCore top-level NuGet package any more. You have to go through all dependencies (and their dependencies, and so on...) yourself and update the individual dependencies.

If your project still uses packages.config files then you should be able to see all available updates in the NuGet package manager.

If your project uses PackageReferences then you should be able to use the `dotnet list package --include-transitive --outdated` ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-list-package)) command to find all referenced packages that have updates available.
To update those, you can either reference them directly, or use [Central Package Management with Transitive pinning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/central-package-management#transitive-pinning).

Comment: Yep, I am aware of that post (as you can see by my question there). That being said, thanks for writing up the answer. I'd be happy throw you an extra bounty if you could point me at a relatively automated way to do this (given that I have roughly 20 projects, each with 3-6 NuGet references).

Comment: Using Central Package Management with Transitive pinning would be somewhat automated because it affects all projects in a solution/folder. But if you don't use Central Package Management already you'd have to migrate all projects to that first.

Comment: You do need an updated NuGet package, but it doesn't have to be the top-level Microsoft.AspNetCore package. You'd have to find which transient dependency was updated (e.g. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features - just an example, not saying you need to update this). Then you could pin the updated version of that transient dependency in CPM.

Comment: Yeah, that won't work - since I believe those packages have _also_ not been released due to the package deprecation effort. :( https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features/5.0.17

Comment: You need to look for updates in the 2.1.x version range. The 2.1.x packages have not been marked as deprecated and *should* receive updates.

Comment: Well I would have sworn I checked and they weren't updated - but clearly I am wrong. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/2.1.34

Comment: But updating to https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/2.1.34, alas, doesn't include the SameSite=None patch. It is cunningly hidden over in https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers/2.1.14 .